# Assign bit field member to char

Tags: c

I have some code here that uses bitsets to store many 1 bit values into a char.

Basically

```
struct BITS_8 {
  char _1:1;
  (...)
  char _8:1;
}
```

Now i was trying to pass one of these bits as a parameter into a function

```
void func(char bit){
  if(bit){
    // do something
  }else{
    // do something else
  }
}

// and the call was
struct BITS_8 bits;
// all bits were set to 0 before
bits._7 = 1;
bits._8 = 0;
func(bits._8);
```

The solution was to single the bit out when calling the function:

```
func(bits._8 & 0x80);
```

But i kept going into `//do something` because other bits were set. I was wondering if this is the correct behaviour or if my compiler is broken. The compiler is an embedded compiler that produces code for freescale ASICs.

EDIT: 2 mistakes: the passing of the parameter and that bits._8 should have been 0 or else the error would make no sense.

**Clarification**

I am interested in what the standard has to say about the assignment

```
struct X{
   unsigned int k:6;
   unsigned int y:1;
   unsigned int z:1;
}

X x;
x.k = 0;
x.y = 1;
x.z = 0;

char t = X.y;
```

Should now `t` contain `1` or `b00000010`?

Comment: `128 == 0x80`, I think you wanted that.

Comment: iirc correctly, a bitfield defined as char _a:1 can only take the values 0 or 1 as it's 1 bit wide, so `func(bits._8 & 0x1);` is the right thing to do.

Comment: The code you have works just fine for me, not sure what your issue is.

Comment: Really? What computer exists today where saving 7 bits makes a difference? Bit fields are less efficient than bytes because they are less than the smallest addressable unit (a byte), so the compiler generates tons more assembly to access the one bit. And the compiler will probably stick in the other 7 bits anyway and just add range checks. Don't use bit fields. If you need this kind of thing, use C++'s `std::bitset`

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Probably has something to do with architecture or endianness.

Comment: @Linuxios I think you're totally missing the point here, he's developing for an ASIC, so pretty deep embedded stuff and at that level there are at least a bazillion good reason to a) avoid C++ and b) fiddle with individual bits

Comment: @fvu exactly thats my point. I actually expected i didn't have to binary and anything, since that is one bit only. But the compiler seems to be doing something weird, so that is what i was asking about.

Comment: try making all the `char`s `unsigned`, just a guess... But if this is a gcc port then most probably they already are `unsigned`

Comment: @unkulunkulu this was never written for any of the popular compilers. It was written specifically for this embedded compiler

Comment: It seems like this is reinventing a packed enum?

Comment: @technosaurus if the compiler supported pack() directive then yes. But it does not.

Comment: @RedX, anyway, does changing the `char`s to `unsigned` have any effect?

Comment: @unkulunkulu no. Assembler generated is: `ldd _status2; beq L1203;` Which pretty much means it still compares the whole struct and not just the one member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was a compiler bug. I wrote the people that produce the compiler and they confirmed it. It only happens if you have a bitfield with an inline function.

Their recommended solution is (if i don't want to wait for a patch)

```
func((char)bits._8));
```

The other answers are right about the correct behaviour. Still i'm marking this one as the answer as it is the answer to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you *can* set a 1-bit *char* to 1. That one bit is left to determine whether it's signed or not, so you end up with the difference between `0` and `-1`.

What you want is an `unsigned char`, to hide this signing bit. Then you can just use 1s and 0s.

Comment: they're more like `0` and `-1`, but it might be the problem, yes

Comment: the thing is that `char` can be `unsigned` by the standard and gcc, for example, defaults to `unsigned char` sometimes (don't know whether it's architecture dependent).

Comment: Okay that was actually only an example bit. The real bit i had this nuisance was 0x4.

Answer (score 0):

Over the years I've grown a bit suspicious when it comes to these specific compilers, quite often their interpretation of what could be described the finer points of the C standard isn't great.  In those cases a more pragmatic approach can help you to avoid insanity, and to get the job done.  What this means in this case is that, if the compiler isn't behaving rationally (which you could define as behaving totally different from what gcc does), you help it a bit.

For example you could modify func to become:

```
void func(char bit){
  if(bit & 1){ // mask off everything that's none of its business
    // do something
  }else{
    // do something else
  }
}
```

And wrt your addon question: t should contain 1.  It can't contain 10 binary because the variable is only 1 bit wide.

Some reading material from the [last publicly available draft for C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

Paragraph 6.7.2.1

> 4 A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified
>   version of _Bool, signed int, unsigned int, or some other
>   implementation-defined type.

(which to me means that the compiler should at least handle your second example correctly) and

> 9 A bit-field is interpreted as a signed or unsigned integer type
>   consisting of the specified number of bits.107) If the value 0 or 1 is
>   stored into a nonzero-width bit-field of type
>   _Bool, the value of the bit-field shall compare equal to the value stored.

As your compiler is meant for embedded use, where bitfields are a rather important feature, I'd expect their implementation to be correct - if they claim to have bitfields implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I can see why you might want to use char to store flags if Bool is typedef'd to an unsigned int or similar or if your compiler does not support packed enums.  You can set up some "flags" using macros (I named them for their place values below, but it makes more sense to name them what they mean)  If 8 flags is not enough, this can be extended to other types up to sizeof(type)*8 flags.

```
/* if you cannot use a packed enum, you can try these macros 
 * in combination with bit operations on the "flags"
 * example printf output is: 1,1,6,4,1 
 * hopefully the example doesn't make it more confusing
 * if so see fvu's example */

#include <stdio.h> /* for printf */
#define ONE ((char) 1)
#define TWO (((char) 1)<<1)
#define FOUR (((char) 1)<<2)
#define EIGHT (((char) 1)<<3)
#define SIXTEEN (((char) 1)<<4)
#define THIRTYTWO (((char) 1)<<5)
#define SIXTYFOUR (((char) 1)<<6)
#define ONETWENTYEIGHT (((char) 1)<<7)

int main(void){
printf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n",ONE & ONE, ONE | ONE, TWO | 6, FOUR & 6, sizeof(ONE));
}
```